# TFS 2013 build how to make workspace files editable?

Tags: c++, tfs, version

I'm working on transferring our old C++ codebase from the Perl-based build process we were using (I know, I know) to a custom TFS build. One of the things I need to do is edit a version.h file that bakes some version info into our code.

However, when I create my workspace and try to edit any of the files with a custom activity of mine, it reports that the workspace is write-only. How do I remove this restriction? I can see that Activities.CreateWorkspace has a security option, but I can't find any good documentation on how I can use that.

Any TFS gurus willing to help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "[File](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20file%20build%20activity&referringTitle=Documentation)" activity from the [TFS Community Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/releases/view/113567) to toggle the read-only flag on the file(s).

Alternatively you could create your own activity from their source.

Comment: The File thing works just fine. Basically, I make eahc file writable before I write the versioning info to it.

Comment: Yep, and you can use a pattern match to save iterating through each one.